# Python mechanize form submiting problem

Tags: python, mechanize

http://klepec.amebis.si/

A want to submit to this form, but the standard submit code from mechanize examples does not work. The "submit" event happens, but the data submitted is empty. This website consist of 2 frames (glavni.asp and vnos.htm) glavni-main vnos-input.
Since mechanize doesn't support frames I tried opening both frames seperatly.

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://klepec.amebis.si/vnos.htm")
br.select_form(name="obrazec")
br["besedilo"] = raw_input("Jaz: ")
response = br.submit()
```

That's actually a "local" version of something like cleverbot. Any ideas, does it have anything to do with the fact that it's made in asp? (I'm kinda new to mechanize)

Comment: The problem was that the text field value was not the one submitted, but it was another read-only variable. That variable's value was set by javascript which doesn't run in mechanize. To correctly pass the value I used the url. http:\\klepec.amebis.si\glavni.asp?vprasanje=value, where vprasanje is the read-only value.

Answer (score 0):

Many people recommend using [twill formfill module](http://twill.idyll.org/extensions.html) instead of raw mechanize.
Try that and tell us if the submit still fails?

Comment: Same error appears. I tried with twill's internal form commands (formvalue) and with the formfill module.

Comment: Troubleshoot it by checking it submits on other ASP sites (with or without JS)? Or contact the site admin? From your latest comment, seems JavaScript may be causing this - can you post more details?